# Precompiled header for moc_* in Visual Studio with Qt add-in

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, plugins, precompiled-headers

I try to make moc.exe to add a precompiled header include into generated moc_* files in Visual Studio with Qt plugin.

I tried to add a PRECOMPILED_HEADER=myheader.h (also with quotes) line into project's preprocessor definitions, that didn't work.

I also tried to add -DPRECOMPILED_HEADER=myheader.h as a parameter for moc.exe in the project *.vcxproj file.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open `Qt project settings` (from context menu of vcxproj in VS) there you'll have `moc options`, in there you can use something like: `-b stdafx.h`

Note in VS2019 the integration changed and you have the Qt options integrated into the default options dialog, there you have `Qt Meta-Object Compiler` and an `Force Include` option, here you should not need the `-b` flag (but, you'll need to test that if this is the case). For more info you can check the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html).

Comment: Adding `-b stdafx.h` didn't make moc.exe to add an `#include <stdafx.h>` line at the beginning of moc_ files. However I managed to create a `Qt Empty Application` in Visual Studio 2017, where the `Qt Meta-Object Compiler` option is available. But I wonder is it possible to do this another way for an empty C++ project.

Comment: Why do you want moc for an empty C++ project? Also i use that option and it works, can you check that you actually re-run moc after you added the option?

Comment: Zlatomir I mean I want to create my project like a regular empty C++ project, without Qt stuff in its settings from the beginning.

Comment: Yes, but why? When you have the integration in place, why would you want to do it manually

Comment: I don't say that I won't use this "Qt Application" option, I just wanted to figure out why the "-b" option is not working for me :)

Comment: Ok. The "-b myheader.hpp" option now works, for some reason. I tried to rebuild my solutuion earlier but moc did not append the include line. I'm not sure what I did wrong. But now it works, thank you! I also will try the "-f" option for science.

Comment: Nevermind, i'm pretty sure it's _-b_ (because i have it working in my project), but i don't see that option in the documentation... weird

Comment: Probably you didn't do a re-build and moc was not executed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `-fstdafx.h -f../%(Identity)` to the moc.exe command line works for me.